# How to compile Java project with IntelliJ and run in terminal (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I like IntelliJ for it's ease of use and great IDE functionality. However, due to the nature of my project, I want to run the relevant .class files through the terminal after having built everything in IntelliJ. My structure looks like this:

```
out/
|
|-production/
|  |
|  |-AILab2/
|     |
|     |-TTT/
|     |  |--Main.class
|     |  |--Constants.class
|     |  |--Deadline.class
|     |  |--pipe|
|     |  |--etc...
|     |
|     |-TTT3
|        |--Constants.class
|        |--Deadline.class
|        |--etc...
src
|
|-TTT
|  |--Main.java
|  |--Constants.java
|  |--Deadline.java
|  |--etc...
|
|-TTT3
   |--Constants.java
   |--Deadline.java
   |--etc...
```

When I go into the terminal to run, I do the following:

```
~/IdeaProjects/AILab2/out/production/AILab2/TTT$ java Main init verbose < pipe | java Main > pipe
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TTT/Main (wrong name: Main)
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TTT/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

I've searched the web and I don't understand the reason for this error. I've run previous projects the same way, but this time, it doesn't work. Grateful for help.

Edit: Changing terminal command to include `TTT` resulted in same message:

```
$ java TTT.Main init verbose < pipe | java TTT.Main > pipe
Error: Could not find or load main class TTT.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TTT.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class TTT.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TTT.Main
```

Comment: @GhostCat, I have edited my question to text instead of screen shots. Also, your solution (or the way I interpreted it) didn't work :/. I've shown what happens in the edit.

Comment: Yes, I am, all files in TTT and TTT3 have `package TTT;` and `package TTT3;` in them, respectively. And yes, Main.java is a file in the TTT package. I've updated my question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class must include the package (TTT.Main), and you have to invoke Java in the parent directory, the one that contains the TTT folder.

And rest assured: it always works like this. The only explanation for "it worked like this before" is: your classes weren't in a distinct package then!

Beyond that, you have to learn how classes are found within the class path. Start reading here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html for example.

Comment: Thanks. BTW; The dot fell away in your provided URL, and SO doesn't let me fix it without editing your post more, which I don't want to. Maybe you want to change it yourself.